# Full Page Width Table - HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

This simply sets up a table and sets the width to 100% but the table does not stretch the width of the page.

***Apparently it works in Firefox 4. I have been testing in Chrome 11***

http://jsfiddle.net/CWNJM/

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    table, th, td
    {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body >
<table align="center" >
    <tr><td align="center" valign="middle"><img width="100%" border='0' id="main_img" src="http://example.com/EiE99"/></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just tried your code in FF 4 and it stretched perfectly fine, even continued to stretch dynamically as I resized the window.

Comment: it's working just fine in the link you provided.

Comment: I don't have that version yet, but chrome 10 works good too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't working properly in Webkit (Google Chrome dev channel). The containing element needs at least one of these two:

```
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

Then it works. I used `body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`

Edit: Seems like `padding: 0;` was what was needed in that particular "jsfiddle".